# Backpress sound played twice when overriding onBackPressed()

Tags: android, android-activity, onbackpressed

I'm working on a music player for android.
In it I have an activity which contains ListView that displays songs/artists/albums etc.
I keep track of the lists the user views (For example all album --> artist x --> album y)
In order to provide a way for the user to go back in the lists, I override `onBackPressed()` so it will pick the previous list the user viewed (handled by a Stack)

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        if (ListActivity.onScreenList == ListActivity.ALL_SONGS && viewStack.empty())
            super.onBackPressed();
        else if (viewStack.empty())
            navListView.performItemClick(navListView.getChildAt(0), 0, navListView.getChildAt(0).getId());
        else
        {
            TypeAndName tan = viewStack.pop();
            if (tan.getName() == null)
            {
                int num = tan.getType();
                navListView.performItemClick(navListView.getChildAt(num), num, navListView.getChildAt(num).getId());
            }
            else
            {
                switch (tan.getType())
                {
                    case ARTISTS:
                        break;
                    case ALBUMS:
                    {
                        Album alb = albumListAdapter.getAlbumAtPosition(position);
                        c = db.rawQuery(DatabaseHandler.qryGetSongsByAlbum, new String[] { alb.getAlbumName() });
                        songListAdapter.setPlaylist(DatabaseHandler.convertCursorToSongsArray(c));
                        lv.setAdapter(songListAdapter);
                        ListActivity.onScreenList = ListActivity.ALL_SONGS;
                    }
                        break;
                    case GENRES:
                        break;
                    case PLAYLISTS:
                        break;
                    case YEAR:
                        break;
                // TODO add other options here

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

the weird part is, that the back sound (the one that is played whenever you press the back button) is played twice.
However, the `onBackPressed()` method is not called twice and the code works as expected.

Comment: is the sound triggered regardless of the condition met in your onbackpressed method? `super.onBackPressed();` triggers it..

Comment: The sound is triggered twice whenever it does not execute `super.onBackPressed()`